# Jquery Custom Parser Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I have a table which have `input` field in the 2 nd column (`1st if started with index 0`). It works fine and sort all regular columns except the column which have textboxes. Here's what I've,

**Javascript Code**

```
<script src="jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#ordertbldata').tablesorter({ 
    headers: { 
        1: {
            sorter: 'textbox_text'
        }
    } 
});

$.tablesorter.addParser({
   id: 'textbox_text',
   is: function(s) {
       console.log('function is called');
       return false;
   },
   format: function(s) {
       console.log('function format called');
       return $($.trim(s)).val();
   },
   type: "text"
});
</script>
```

I've added `log` function to debug but the function isn't called. What's wrong I'm doing here ?

**UPDATE** : [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/01e7x0ck/1/)

Comment: return in `format` doesn't make sense , did you try inspecting what `s` is and what `$.trim(s)` is? Create a demo

Comment: put it in a sandbox we have access to ...jsfiddle.net, jsbin, plnkr.co, codepen, etc.

Comment: reasonably easy to fix following docs https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-advanced.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your demo was declaring the parser after initializing the plugin.

Seems to work well with this configuration

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
   id: 'textbox_text',
   is: function(s) {           
       return false;
   },
   format: function(s,table, el) {        
       return $.trim($(el).find('input').val().toLowerCase());       
   },
   type: "text",
   parsed: true,
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/01e7x0ck/4/)**</kbd>